# Zener diode, clipper circuit

Tags: zener, homework, voltage-clipping

This is the original assignment. My solution attempt is below that.

> Explain the output expected from the following circuit and also identify the name of circuit.
>
> (Where VZ is Zener voltages for ZD1 and ZD2 and V1= Vp/4, VZ = Vp/2)
>
> [image: Look for the circuit in the picture]

---

I did try to solve this question, but I am not sure whether my analysis is correct or not.

As the given circuit is a clipper circuit with a DC bias of Vp/4, I am getting the output wave form to be:

[image]

As ZD1 has breakdown voltage of Vp/2, the positive half cycle is clipped at Vp/2+Vp/4=3Vp/4 and in the negative half cycle the ZD1 acts forward biased but ZD2 is reverse biased, so it is clipped at -Vp/2+Vp/4=-Vp/4.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework no attempt at solution.

Comment: Hi! As explained above, homework questions without your own attempt aren't answered here – we can't know where you are stuck, and what you actually need help with. So, explain to us how far you've come, and where you need the help to make your own next step.

Comment: Swaroop Ch - Welcome :-) As commented, for assignment / test / homework-type questions like this, we need to see your own work *first*. That is currently missing, so your question has been "[closed](/help/closed-questions)". However as explained in that link, it will automatically be put in a queue to consider re-opening it, if within 5 days you [Edit] your question, add your analysis & your best solution attempt so far (which parts of the question *can* you attempt?) and make it clear *exactly* where you are stuck. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry guys.......

Comment: Now re-opening the question, as a solution attempt has been added.

Comment: Your last equation doesn't make sense. Can you look at that again?

Comment: Its auto edited ...now I re-edited it

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's rare to see someone actually show their work after having the question closed, good to see that you actually seem to care about learning rather than just having someone answer your homework for you (as many of the people who post homework problems on here seem to want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During +ve cycle :  when Vin = Vp

```
               Drop across Zd1 =Vp/2

               therefore max magnitude is Vp/2+ Vp/4 = 3Vp/4
```

During -ve cycle: when Vin =-Vp

```
              Drop across Zd2 = Vp/2

              min magnitude = -Vp/2 +Vp/4 = -Vp/4
```

I feel this approach is right, Is this how you calculated the maxima and minima for the plot?

Comment: Yes.Thank you btw

Comment: @swaroop-ch Please mark this answer as accepted so mr Hari Krishna can get his deserved points for helping you out :)